# AEM deployment from atom editor

Tags: aem, atom-editor

I am using Atom editor to work on AEM project. 
Is there any package available for atom to deploy changes from editor to Aem server, just like a plugin is provided with brackets editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the time of this answer, the only extension I know of is [vlt-atom](https://atom.io/packages/vlt-atom).